# How can i get sorted data according to order key using JSONDecoder?

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I am getting the response from API and going to parse response using 'JSONDecoder' and able to parse but I want the sorted array of 'FieldModel' according to 'order' key in "content" object of "ContentModel" auto when I decode using JSONDecoder?

> My response from API:

```
{content = (
    {
        fieldName = \"$.alcohol.beer\";
        label = Beer;
        order = 2;
    },
                {
        fieldName = \"$.alcohol.wine\";
        label = Wine;
        order = 1;
    },
       {
        fieldName = \"$.alcohol.any\”;
        label = Wine;
        order = 3;
    }
);}
```

> My models:

```
struct ContentModel: Codable {
    var content: [FieldModel]?
}

struct FieldModel: Codable {
    var fieldName: String?
    var order: Int?
    var label: String?
}
```

> Code for decode the data:

```
 let myFinalData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ContentModel.self, from: jsonData)
```

**How can I get content of ContentModel will be sorted according to order key after decode using above code?**

Comment: `myFinalData.content = myFinalData.content.sorted { ($0.order ?? 0) < ($1.order ?? 0) }`. It won't be nice with all the optionals you have.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to use manual sort means when data is parsing using JSONDecoder then it will autosave sorted data in content. I don't want to add/use any code of line after parsing. before parsing how can I add this sorting code?

Comment: Then just write that into `init(from: Decoder)`.

Comment: this is not a json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goals by creating a custom `init(from decoder)` method for your `ContentModel` struct, where you use the `order` property of the `FieldModel` elements to assign the `FieldModel`s to their respective place in the `content` array.

I'd also suggest making all field of your structs immutable and non-optional unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

```
struct ContentModel: Codable {
    let content: [FieldModel]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case content
    }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let content = try container.decode([FieldModel].self, forKey: .content)
        var orderedContent = content
        for element in content {
            orderedContent[element.order-1] = element
        }
        self.content = orderedContent
    }
}

struct FieldModel: Codable {
    let fieldName: String
    let label: String
    let order: Int
}
```

Comment: I don't want to pass criticism on the solution per se but sorting while decoding – as desired by the OP –  is much more expensive (and inefficient) than one `.sorted {...}` line **after** the decoding.